# Karate mock handling of context variables - changed since v1.0.0?

Tags: karate

I have a simple mock script that counts the number of times an endpoint is pinged (holding the count in context, which is setup in the 'Background' construct):

```
Feature: service mock

Background:
  * def pingCount = 0
  * def nextCount = function(){ return ~~++pingCount }
  
Scenario: pathMatches('service/v1/ping') && methodIs('get')
  * def response = {}
  * set response.message = 'this is a service'
  * set response.pingCount = nextCount()
  * def responseStatus = 200
```

startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar karate-<version>.jar \
-m src/test/java/provider/service.feature \
-p 1311
```

Where `<version>` is the karate standalone release number.

The karate code works as expected with standalone jar version 0.9.5:

```
> curl -X GET http://localhost:1311/service/v1/ping
{"message":"this is a service","pingCount":1}
> curl -X GET http://localhost:1311/service/v1/ping
{"message":"this is a service","pingCount":2}
> curl -X GET http://localhost:1311/service/v1/ping
{"message":"this is a service","pingCount":3}
```

It doesn't work with versions 1.0.0+ (counter not incremented):

```
> curl -X GET http://localhost:1311/service/v1/ping
{"message":"this is a service","pingCount":1}
> curl -X GET http://localhost:1311/service/v1/ping
{"message":"this is a service","pingCount":1}
> curl -X GET http://localhost:1311/service/v1/ping
{"message":"this is a service","pingCount":1}
> curl -X GET http://localhost:1311/service/v1/ping
{"message":"this is a service","pingCount":1}
```

Has mock context variable handling changed since 1.0.0? I couldn't find anything in the docs to suggest it had.

Does anyone know if I need to change the scripts for compatibility with versions 1.0.0+ and where supporting documentation is located?

I haven't used karate for a while so it could be that things have moved on!

I am expecting the same behaviour from the given script using versions 1.0.0+ as I'm getting from 0.9.5.

Thanks for any help that's forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try 1.3.0.RC2 ?

If you still see the change, there's not much we can do - the whole JS engine had to be replaced and in hindsight I think we managed to keep things mostly working the same.

There are workarounds. For example this might work:

```
* def nextCount = function(){ var temp = karate.get('pingCount') + 1; karate.set('pingCount', temp); return temp; }
```

Anyone is welcome to contribute code and improve things further of course.

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks for the response. Two things: (1) the workaround works a treat, so thank you for that (2) I couldn't find 1.3.0.RC2 in GitHUb (location https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases) - should I source it from somewhere else? In the meantime I will upgrade to the latest version with the workaround and upgrade to 1.3.0.RC2 ASAP - thanks again.

Comment: @mattk oh, are you using the "standalone jar" - in that case we haven't made a release. unless you are willing to build it yourself: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide - but if you are on Maven, just use that version and it is available. a "final" 1.3 release should be out in less than a month.

Comment: Hi @Peter - yes, I'm using the standalone jar. Happy to wait for the release and will use the workaround until then.  Thanks again for your help with this one.